# How to join two tables with one of them not having a primary key and not the same character length

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am dealing with two tables:
**"dyndomrun.ddid"**  = with a Primary key and 
**"domainregion.domainid"** = without any primary key nor foreign key.

"dyndomrun.ddid" definition is "character varying" and has 8 characters, whereas "domainregion.domainid" definition is also "character varying" but has 10 characters.

Problem : There are some fields in domainregion table that needs to be joined together with the primary key in dyndomrun table. I can't seem to do this using a simple JOIN statement such as below:

```
SELECT domainregion.domainid, domainregion.dombegin, domainregion.domend, dyndomrun.ddid 
FROM domainregion, dyndomrun 
WHERE domainregion.domainid = dyndomrun.ddid 
ORDER BY domainregion.domainid, dyndomrun.ddid, domainregion.dombegin, domainregion.domend;
```

I have tried JOINS, INNER JOINS, LIKE, none of them seems to work. The database that I am dealing with is purely SQL based stored using PostgreSQL.

Is there a method that i can use in which it selects the domainregion.domainid based on the length of the character and matching it dyndomrun.ddid?

Please advise.

Comment: cast the larger of the 2 to the other datatype/precision when doing the join

Comment: where left(domaainregion.domainID,8)=left(dyndomrun.ddid,8) may need padding of spaces. (but this is the general idea, not a "SPECIFIC answer"

Comment: Is is something like this `select CAST (domainregion.domainid AS "DomainRegion" AND dyndomrun.ddid AS "DynDomrun")
from domainregion, dyndomrun
where left(domainregion.domainid,8)=left(dyndomrun.ddid,8)
order by domainregion.domainid, dyndomrun.ddid;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to compare the first 8 characters only:

```
SELECT r.domainid, r.dombegin, r.domend, d.ddid 
FROM   domainregion r
JOIN   dyndomrun d ON r.domainid::varchar(8) = d.ddid 
ORDER  BY r.domainid, d.ddid, r.dombegin, r.domend;
```

The cast implicitly trims trailing characters. `ddid` only has 8 characters to begin with. No need to process it, too. This achieves the same:

```
JOIN   dyndomrun d ON left(r.domainid, 8) = d.ddid
```

However, be advised that the string function `left()` was only introduced with PostgreSQL 9.1. In earlier versions you can substitute:

```
JOIN   dyndomrun d ON substr(r.domainid, 1, 8) = d.ddid
```

__

#### Basic explanation for beginners:

- The query uses a `JOIN`. Read [more about that in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).
- `FROM domainregion r` is short for `FROM domainregion AS r`. `AS` is just noise in this case in PostgreSQL. The **table alias** makes the query shorter and easier to read but has no other impact in here. You can also use table aliases to include the same table multiple times for instance.
- The join condition `ON r.domainid::varchar(8) = d.ddid` joins only those rows together where the two expressions match exactly. Again, read about those [basics in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) (or any other source).

It's a simple query, not much to explain here.

Comment: may i ask what does domainregion "r" stands for ?

Comment: it's an alias so you don't have to type domainregion every time. where you see r.domainid it means substitute domainregion for "R"

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. However, i have another problem. Do you mind taking a look at it for me . [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645230/join-three-tables-with-one-of-them-not-having-a-primary-key)

Comment: @jeiman90: I added some basic explanation and links to my answer.