# Join three tables with one of them not having a primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, primary-key

I have three tables that i would like to join up together.

```
Domain table
-domainid - Primary key

DomainRegion table
-domainid - Don't have a Primary Key or Foreign Key
-dombegin
-domend

DynDomrun table
-ddid - Primary Key
-confid1
-confid2
```

"domain.domainid", "domainregion.domainid" and "dyndomrun.ddid" have the same type of data types, "character varying".

Now, the problem is that "domain.domainid" and "domainregion.domainid" has two extra characters in it that i can't seem to do a join with "dyndomrun.ddid".

However, "domainid" is related to "ddid", just that "domainregion.domainid" is not assigned a primary key or a foreign key and i need some fields from that table to join up with the others.

In the end, I need to have a single, full table listing the "dyndomrun.ddid, domainregion.dombegin, domainregion.domend, dyndomrun.confid1, dyndomrun.confid2".

I have tried using `where ("domain.domainid",8)=left("dyndomrun.ddid",8)`, it gave me an error stating

`ERROR:  function left(character varying, integer) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.`

I have tried using joins, and other sql statements and they all don't seem to work.

Any ideas as to how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: As Erwin said in the original topic, the left() function only exists for postgres >= 9.x. Use substr() instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to join two tables with one of them not having a primary key and not the same character length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636956/how-to-join-two-tables-with-one-of-them-not-having-a-primary-key-and-not-the-sam)

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much. Your previous solution did work. It now returns all the required rows that i need to make a comparison.

Comment: Do you mind explaining as to how your solution works? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636956/how-to-join-two-tables-with-one-of-them-not-having-a-primary-key-and-not-the-sam), you also need to read up on the [syntax of identifiers in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS).

This:

```
"domain.domainid"
```

would have to be

```
"domain"."domainid"
```

Or better yet, simply:

```
domain.domainid
```

Comment: Thank you Erwin. As to your solution you posted in my post earlier, do you mind explaining it to me as I am a beginner at SQL. Thank you again.